# Could a skyhook with double pendulum catch a payload with zero velocity?

Tags: design-alternative, skyhook

It's my understanding the the tip of a rotating skyhook would be travelling at ~3.6 km/s (Mach 10), which presents a major problem.

Could this be overcome by attaching a second, smaller, also rotating tether to the tip of the main tether, which would at various times be stationary relative to the ground?

Since the skyhook is already rotating in the opposite direction to the Earth, that rotation is already reducing the ground speed of the tip.  But I'd like it reduced all the way down to zero, to enable easier pickups.

Relevant: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/525999/how-does-the-perigee-of-a-skyhook-travel-slower-than-the-apogee

Comment: Why not just double the rotation rate of the sky hook?

Comment: Presumably that would degrade the tether or something.  I'm not sure.

Comment: One obvious objection to this idea is that a [double pendulum is chaotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_pendulum).

Comment: a double pendulum is chaotic, but as the skyhook is freely rotating and not supported by a fulcrum, it is not a pendulum.  And your proposed second arm (if counterweighted) would not introduce unsteady forcing

Answer (score 2):

Answer: not necessary.

A skyhook has the same geometry as a planetary gear set. In the sketch, the Earth is rotating (green) and the CM of the Skyhook assembly is orbiting (Blue). The skyhook rotates (Red) so there is no relative motion between Skyhook and Earth at the point where they mesh.

The Earth’s rotational speed and the orbital speed of the Skyhook in LEO are given, but the Skyhook rotational speed can be chosen to provide zero relative velocity .

[image]

No "double pendulum" required.

Comment: You are describing a special case of a skyhook, which is the "CardioRotovator" concept, from the [2001 Boeing HASTOL](https://www.niac.usra.edu/files/studies/final_report/355Bogar.pdf) study.  They found that "such a design would require a very large counterweight, on the order of 1000–2000 times the mass of the payload, and the tether would need to be mechanically reeled in after collecting each payload in order to maintain synchronization between the tether rotation and its orbit."

Comment: @MichaelCurrie ... the OP question was "Could a skyhook with double pendulum catch a payload with zero velocity?" The posted answer explains that a skyhook without a double pendulum could could catch a payload with zero velocity, so a double pendulum is not necessary to meet the zero-velocity requirement. All skyhook proposals are impractical for a variety of reasons, but the OP was not asking about practicality.